# What is the angel in the Star Trek: Discovery title sequence?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

What is the angel silhouette in the title sequence? The opening is starkly different from other series themes. What does the angel mean?

---

<sup>*Please use [spoiler markdown](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-important-to-mark-spoiler-questions-as-such) in your answers.*</sup>

Comment: I believe it's kinda the whole point of season 2.

Comment: Yeah, if you're currently watching the show, beware of any answers to this, as they could completely a major plot point.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Angel - Warning. Extreme spoilers.

Comment: **You DO NOT want the answer to this question.** It's kinda the whole point of the entire show. That's already saying too much. In fact, -1, because this is akin to asking what *rosebud* means. Your welcome.

Comment: @Mazura That's not a reason to downvote. How would OP know that's spoiler-capable?

Answer (score 11):

Okay, as spoiler-free as possible:

The Red Angel is a mysterious entity or phenomenon witnessed by Starfleet in various locations around the galaxy. It was given its name by a person who had also seen it many years in the past.

Season 2 of the series is largely about the search for the nature of the Red Angel.

As the comments have pointed out, [this link](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Angel) has more information, but even glancing at the page could give away important plot revelations.